# Camel how to add something to registry - with java, in general

Tags: apache-camel

sometimes I have to add an object to camel registry (of course with java). In most cases it is a dataSource .

My problem is I can't figure out a general working way.

I always begin to acquire the registry:

```
getContext().getRegistry();
```

But "Registry" does not have any method to add an object. So I have to try (with debugger) what kind of registry is in use

```
getContext().getRegistry(some.class)<some method to add something>;
```

For example in one project (camel blueprint) I have to call

```
SimpleRegistry registry = new SimpleRegistry();
registry.put("some", bean);
getContext().getRegistry(CompositeRegistry.class).addRegistry(registry);
```

Now I created a project with same structure (also same maven parent) but now the code from above stops working because for some reason now camel uses a `PropertyPlaceholderDelegateRegistry` I am sure there will be code to add my bean but;

Is there code that works with every setup to add something to camels registry?

Comment: A slightly different solve:
see https://stackoverflow.com/a/70544714/7988084

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is one way of adding stuff to the registry in a RouteBuilder class. Below I am adding a TCPServerInitializerFactory which will be used later on. I always use the camel-blueprint archetype but create routes using java dsl. This works fine for me.

```
TCPServerInitializerFactory serverFactory = new TCPServerInitializerFactory(null);
final CamelContext camelContext = getContext();
        final org.apache.camel.impl.SimpleRegistry registry = new org.apache.camel.impl.SimpleRegistry();
        final org.apache.camel.impl.CompositeRegistry compositeRegistry = new org.apache.camel.impl.CompositeRegistry();
        compositeRegistry.addRegistry(camelContext.getRegistry());
        compositeRegistry.addRegistry(registry);
        ((org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext) camelContext).setRegistry(compositeRegistry);
    registry.put("spf", serverFactory);
```

Comment: Am sure there is a tidier way but most approaches I found was for the pure java approach rather than the blueprint/osgi one that I work with.

Comment: what would be a pure java approach?

Comment: See an example here: http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.apache.camel.impl.SimpleRegistry

Answer (score 2):

For Camel 3.x use the code snippet for adding in registry at runtime

```
DefaultRegistry registry = (DefaultRegistry) camelContext.getRegistry();
registry.bind("key", <Object to bind>);
((org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext) camelContext).setRegistry(registry);
```

This can be referred further,
[enter link description here](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/camel-3-migration-guide.html#_checked_vs_unchecked_exceptions)

Comment: why is the registry being set on the context again in the last line?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Spring with camel you can register your bean in Application context and it will be get registered in ApplicationContextRegistry.

eg. ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory = ((ConfigurableApplicationContext)
applicationContext).getBeanFactory();
beanFactory.registerSingleton("beantolookup", bean);

And you can look up
camelContext.getRegistry().lookupByName("beantolookup")

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to solve:

1. Create a Camel Listener ( I have a standalone Java Camel App).
2. Add to `beforeConfigure()`  method a section similar to below.

   ```
    CamelContext mainCamelContext = main.getCamelContext();
    DefaultRegistry defaultRegistry = mainCamelContext.getRegistry(DefaultRegistry.class);
    defaultRegistry.bind("YouBeanName", new YourBeanClassName());
   ```

Once this is done - you can reference it in your XML DSL.

Tested using Camel 3.14.x, JDK 8.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the `camel-spring` package, you can use Spring to manage the registry. Here's an example of code I used to add a singleton bean in Java through Spring:

MyApplicationContext.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring       http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">

    <bean id="myRouteBuilder" class="com.example.MyRouteBuilder"/>

    <camel:camelContext id="my-camel-context">
        <camel:routeBuilder ref="myRouteBuilder"/>
    </camel:camelContext>
</beans>
```

MyApplication.java

```java
public class MyApplication {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final FileSystemXmlApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("/path/to/MyApplicationContext.xml");
    }
}
```

MyRouteBuilder.java

```java
public void MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder implements ApplicationContextAware {
    @Override
    public void configure() {
        from("ftps://localhost:21/foo?pollStrategy=#myPollingStrategy")
            .log("${body}");
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(final ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        final ConfigurableApplicationContext context  = (ConfigurableApplicationContext)applicationContext;
        final DefaultListableBeanFactory     registry = (DefaultListableBeanFactory)context.getBeanFactory();
        registry.registerSingleton("myPollingStrategy", new MyPollingStrategy());
    }
}
```

The important part here is to implement the `ApplicationContextAware` interface in the class that you want to use to manually add beans to the registry. This interface can be implemented on any bean that Spring initializes; you don't have to use your RouteBuilder. In this case, the bean is created on startup during the `setApplicationContext(...)` execution before `configure()` is called, but you can also store the application context for use later (which is probably a more common usage).

This was tested with Camel `2.19.0` and Spring `4.3.10-RELEASE`.